# How to fix apache2 timestamps, incorrect values

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2

When I restart my apache2 and reload a page, the log file shows

```
boogie.tontut.fi - - [28/Oct/2008:03:27:49 +0200] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 457 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3"
```

...as supposed to, as it's `03:27:49` now. However, when I click the refresh button again, the new log entry is:

```
boogie.tontut.fi - - [27/Oct/2008:21:27:52 -0400] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 457 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3"
```

Offset has changed from `+0200 to -0400` and I have no clue where this comes from.

How can I start troubleshooting this problem?

Answer (score 1):

sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

## Add time zone

date.timezone="Europe/London"

restart apache2
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Try and set your timezone explicitly in the `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnv TZ GMT+2
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. I tried adding it to apache2.conf as well as in <VirtualHost>.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at the system call would help; on Unix its `gettimeofday` and on Windows its `GetSystemTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible that something that runs in apache is changing locale settings in its environment?

Something like:

1. First reload: log message `GMT+2`
2. Apache runs /weird_script.php that calls some kind of `setlocale()`
3. Second reload, new enviroment setting in effect, results in log message `GMT-4`